# How to select a microscope for deep microscopy? Specifically for Deep Learning/ML model development

Tags: cell-biology, microscopy, data

I am new to biology and microscopy. I am a data scientist. I am faced with a question on selecting a good microscope that enables automation of scanning the slides. And cellular object detection using deep learning.

Considering, my lack of background I am only looking at the resolution of scanned output and the ability of the microscope to provide images that can integrate with a workflow that I am about to develop. As one of the first applications, I am looking to detect sperm cells stained with Christmas Tree stain (head = red/pink, tail = yellow/green) using brightfield microscopy.

What are the **other** criteria I should worry about? What questions should a data scientist ask?

Any general advice will also be valuable.

Comment: Optics Optics Optics - there are a few questions you need to ask yourself and then supply in your question here, the first of which is "what are you looking for?" (cells? what sort?, stained (yes/no, what stain?) The second of which is "how am I looking for it?" This one might involve words like brightfield, fluorescence, confocal . Thirdly - how magnified? Stick to a quality brand (Nikon, Zeiss, Olympus) and you can't go really wrong, but be prepared to spend $100 K. Talk to your local sales reps!

Comment: The first application is the detection/localization of sperm cells using a Christmas tree stain. Brightfield, that is what the team I am working with mentioned. 40x.

Comment: There's already an automated platform out there for [the use-case](https://www.keyence.com/ss/products/microscope/bz-casestudy/christmas-tree-stain.jsp).  I've edited your question to include the information from your comment.

Comment: I would advise someone new to biology and microscopy to outsource this particular decision to someone who is *not* new to biology and microscopy: you need a collaborator. I realize this is probably what you intend to do by asking here, but I think you'll need more hands-on advice and guidance in this endeavor than you can get through StackExchange.

Comment: @BryanKrause I had just come to the same conclusion. I was going to start answering the question, but then realized that I would need to explain pretty much every part of the microscope and its purpose, which would take me far too long to write up, and be far too unwieldy to work in this format.

Comment: I do collaborate with Biology scientists. But I am the only one from a data science background. My question is more limited to the intersection between microscopy and data science. What questions should a data scientist ask when buying a microscope?

Comment: @kosmos: for list of information with possible questions to be induced see [here](https://www.microscopyu.com/tutorials). The questions you should be asking boil down to "what are the best things for my scenario?". This will include lenses, camera (CCD, colour/false colour), mounts, stage automation, illumination, image enhancements (DIC/Normarsky, Phase contrast, others), and even then it will come down to some opinion based things. You really really need to talk to an expert. I suspect that you will need mostly information about the camera data output and maybe drivers etc.

Comment: @kosmos I think the two sides of that question are best served by a conversation between A) You. You're the data scientist. You know what your processing pipeline is going to look like, so you have an idea what data you are going to need to input, and B) Someone who is an expert in microscopy. In particular, automated microscopy, which itself seems like a niche area to me. It's something where you're better off sitting down and having a back-and-forth conversation with someone who has the complementary experience to yours. Probably also a useful third party would be a sales rep.

Comment: @Bryan Krause thanks for your advice. There are biologists in my group but not experts in microscopy; not in an in-depth way.  We are actually talking to sales reps, but difficult to verify their claims. Considering a $100k budget, which is not small for the lab, I have a responsibility to ensure that the new microscope will enable data science applications such as sperm cell detection and potentially more.

Comment: @bob1 I have raised some questions with the sales rep and have requested a meeting with their technical team. My first question is the ability of the microscope/scanner to integrate with the pipeline. Particularly issues with proprietary formats. Regarding image quality, my assumption is that if the human eye can identify it, the machine could be trained to do that with sufficient data.  I find that object detection in microscope images has a challenge that cells are too small amidst a lot of background objects. Considering this and in general, what would you comment on this assumption?

Comment: I think you really need to provide more information on just what you're attempting to do.  Just what do you mean by automating the scanning of slides?  Do you have humans preparing the slides and putting them on the microscope?  Or do you want an automated pipeline to do some or all of that?  For the former,  you could probably (though I'm no expert, by any means) use a much less expensive microscope with a high resolution USB camera.  Especially if you're still in a development phase, where your main concern is getting the software to work.

Comment: Not sure this is answerable here. I suggest trying to get a demo or better yet tell the sales rep that you need to "test drive" their product for x days — where x is significantly more time than your worst case estimate for how long a test run would take. Maybe invoke/invent a manager/supervisor/bean counter who is skeptical and thinks a competitors cheaper scope would be more than sufficient for your needs?  Probably works even better if you actually have specifics about alternatives ...

Comment: For detecting objects like cells, you need a good enough spatial resolution that comes from the choice of objective (the higher the NA, the better the resolution).  No need to worry too much about that, though, if your object is larger than ~1 um. You also need a high dynamic range from the detector, preferably 16-bit or higher, and to make sure that the experimenter will use it. Proprietary software is a problem, mostly if you want to do real-time detection. You can always build your microscope to custom specifications but that requires expertise.

Comment: @vkehayas Thanks for your comment. It is not real-time detection.

Comment: @tyersome These microscopes are quite expensive and getting one for trial is a bit of a problem, especially if they need to come from another country.

Comment: @kosmos In my experience, the more expensive something is the easier it is to get one for a trial. The sales folk know you are making a big investment and are willing to do anything to make it happen. You say you have biologists but not microscopy experts in your group. Biologists aren't good enough - get a microscopy expert, too. For things like proprietary format...that probably comes from the camera rather than microscope. Every camera I've used could output in some sort of bitmap format. Video was more problematic.

Comment: @kosmos if you are doing single image, most software(!) can output in tif format, but this might not be enough for you, depending on your pipeline. I've had good use with [Spot cameras](https://www.spotimaging.com/microscope-cameras/), they have excellent resolution, great optics and good software. They also have a development kit for integration with custom software, which might be useful for you.

Comment: @kosmos regarding your questions in comment - yes, and no. I'm no expert in machine learning or anything, but the trained human eye is very very good at picking up patterns. If the cells are too small cf. other objects, increase the magnification. Optical magnification is better than digital, for reasons that should be clear to you.

Comment: @bob1 thanks for your comments.

Comment: @kosmos - ignore my comments re spot cameras, they were good about 10 years ago, looks like they haven't increased the pixel resolution (5-12 MP) since then. This may not be a problem for you though, and most microscope cameras are in that range anyway. Another option is to get adapters for a D-SLR camera.

Comment: Are automatic sliders available as extensions to microscopes? By automatic slider, I am looking at a process where a few hundred slides are prepared and placed on the slider and it automatically pushes it to the microscope. The microscope does the scanning. The scanner/camera captures the image and stores it on to the cloud or on-premise storage. These images are then either seen by an expert or processed by automated software. I see there are cameras that could be added to microscopes. But looking for automatic sliders as well which work with the cameras.